# ASP.NET MVC 4 Areas within Areas won't render the Shared _Layout.vbhtml from Master project

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, viewengine, areas

Ok so I have this interesting ASP.NET MVC 4 solution/project structure, which creates pluggable application modules. I created it following this technique:

http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx

As a result, I have a main application with an empty Areas folder in the project. I also have a Plugin project that resides in the Areas folder of the main application on disk, and it also sets its build output folder to the main application `\bin` folder.

In my pluggable module application, I decided to create an Areas section within it, and created an Area called Test. By default, the ASP.NET MVC 4 view engine doesn't support it as a pluggable module because it tries to look for the View in the incorrect location.

So conceptually, we have:

```
Main             <- Main application folder
   Areas         <- Main application folder
      Plugin     <- Plugin module application folder
         Areas   <- Plugin module application folder
            Test <- Plugin module application folder
```

To fix this, I created a way to interpret the `AreaName` property in a customized `RazorViewEngine` class to rewrite the URL the view engine is looking for to find the view files in these pluggable module areas.

First, I use the following convention to define my Area registration class for the Test Area belonging to my pluggable modules:

```
Namespace Areas.Plugin
    Public Class PluginAreaRegistration
        Inherits AreaRegistration

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property AreaName() As String
            Get
                Return "Plugin.Test"
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext)
            context.MapRoute( _
                "Plugin_default", _
               "Plugin/Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
                New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional},
                {"Plugin.Test.Controllers"}
            )
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I then inherited the the `RazorViewEngine` and overrode some methods to parse and generate the views path in the pluggable module's Areas folder:

```
Public Class MyExtendedRazorViewEngine
Inherits RazorViewEngine

' set the location format strings
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.PartialViewLocationFormats = _
        {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{3}/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{3}/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{1}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{1}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Areas/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Areas/{1}/Views/{0}.vbhtml"
        }

    MyBase.AreaViewLocationFormats = {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Areas/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Areas/{1}/Views/{0}.vbhtml"
    }

    MyBase.AreaMasterLocationFormats = {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Areas/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Areas/{1}/Views/{0}.vbhtml"
    }

    MyBase.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Areas/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Areas/{1}/Views/{0}.vbhtml"
    }

    MyBase.ViewLocationFormats = {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    }

    MyBase.MasterLocationFormats = {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    }

    MyBase.PartialViewLocationFormats = {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    }

End Sub

Protected Overrides Function CreatePartialView(controllerContext As ControllerContext, partialPath As String) As IView

    Dim area As String = controllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Item("Area")
    Dim areaname As String()
    Dim pp As String = partialPath

    If Not area Is Nothing Then
        areaname = area.Split(".")
        If areaname.Length > 1 Then
            pp = pp.Replace(area, areaname(0) & "/Areas/" & areaname(1))
        End If
    End If

    Return MyBase.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, pp)
End Function

Protected Overrides Function CreateView(controllerContext As ControllerContext, viewPath As String, masterPath As String) As IView

    Dim area As String = controllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Item("Area")
    Dim areaname As String()
    Dim vp As String = viewPath
    Dim mp As String = masterPath
    If Not area Is Nothing Then
        areaname = area.Split(".")
        If areaname.Length > 1 Then
            vp = vp.Replace(area, areaname(0) & "/Areas/" & areaname(1))
            mp = mp.Replace(area, areaname(0) & "/Areas/" & areaname(1))
        End If
    End If

    Return MyBase.CreateView(controllerContext, vp, mp)
End Function

Protected Overrides Function FileExists(controllerContext As ControllerContext, virtualPath As String) As Boolean

    Dim area As String = controllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Item("Area")
    Dim areaname As String()
    Dim vp As String = virtualPath
    If Not area Is Nothing Then
        areaname = area.Split(".")
        If areaname.Length > 1 Then
            vp = vp.Replace(area, areaname(0) & "/Areas/" & areaname(1))
        End If
    End If
    Return MyBase.FileExists(controllerContext, vp)
End Function
End Class
```

I've modified the main application `Global.asax` file to pick up the new view engine:

```
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Optimization

Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)

        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear()
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(New MyExtendedRazorViewEngine())
    End Sub
End Class
```

After launching the browser and invoking the Home controller for my main application, I see the correct pages and layout render. When I go to the Home controller action for the Index for my Plugin module, again the Index view renders properly with the `_Layout.vbhtml` being picked up from the main application.

However, when I invoke the Home controller action for the Index view of Plugin's Test Area, I can only see the Index page view render, but the master `_Layout.vbhtml` isn't being included from the main application.

What am I missing to get the Areas views below the Plugin pluggable module to render the main application's master layout template?

Comment: I have the same problem and I solved it by set Layout property explicitly inside the area views `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`, But I think that is not the solution we are looking for.